# WordPress visual HTML editor breaks the code

Tags: html, wordpress

Once I switch from HTML code to Visual Editor and than switch back, the visual editor significantly changes my initial HTML code removing newlines, restructuring code, etc.

However, without the visual editor I waste a lot of time coding in HTML and than making loads of previews to make sure the page looks nice.

Is there a way to organize the workflow like the descibed below?

1. design page in HTML visually in WordPress or any other place,
2. modify HTML code manually
3. make small edits in visual editor (for
   maitainance) after the page is published without fully restructuring
   the previous code

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing in wordpress for months already, and what i suggest is this:

1) Download Xampp to emulate a server on your local PC

2) Install wordpress on localhost after setting up a local server (matching the online one so that after that you need to do less changes)

3) Select or create your child theme, and add a "develop" wordpress template
[tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

4) On localhost, add a page and set the develop template for this page (the previous tutorial shows this as well). Publish and view that page. At this stage, it should be empty.

5) In the develop template, code using your preferred software using html and css the way you would do in any other not-wordpress projects (NB: don't code **ANYTHING** in the wordpress offline edit page, but all in the template)

6) Now, everytime you change something on the develop template, you just need to reload the page on your browser and you will be able to see all the changes that you made.

7) Once you're happy with the look of the page, copy the whole content from develop template to wordpress page aditor (the live one) and save.

**JOB DONE!**

Now start again on the develop template with another page and repeat this for all the pages you want.

It seams hard, but trust me, it is not! and it makes your life much easier.

**Suggestions:**
Install on wordpress this plugin: [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/)

And when you paste your html code, be sure you paste it inside this tags

```
[raw][/raw]
```

**Why this?**

well, as you may or may not know, wordpress by default close everything into `<p>` tags, it this can ruin the way your code is displayed. To avoid this, if you paste your code inside the mentioned above tags, this won't happen.
You can also disable the

tags adding something to your functions.php file (just search google for that)

Hope this answer was usefull. Good luck!

Comment: How this will actually improve my WordPress page editiing? Does this accelerate ediiting because of using local server to reduce WordPress response time? Or does this simplify HTML design or adds an improved visual capabilities?

Comment: It improves both. I mean, first of all, you can use a proper code editor, with markup, line embedding and errors, suggestions etc, not just a simple text area where you can only type plain text. Other that that yes, the speed time. In your local machine, it is basically already loaded and if you do what i suggested with the develop template, once you add the template to the page and click on "view page" the first time, then you just need to refresh the browser tab to see the edits and not editing nothing on the wordpress page editor, so way faster and easier...

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins to add this functionality, something like :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-editor-syntax-highlighter/

Description :

Add syntax highlighting to the Post/Page HTML editor.

Features
-Syntax highlighting in the Post/Page HTML editor
-Save your posts and pages pressing Ctrl+S (Cmd+S on Mac)
-Restore cursor position after page is reloaded
-Light and Dark editor colour themes
-New fullscreen mode.
-Toggle fullscreen mode with F11/Esc hotkeys

https://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup-plus/

Description :

This plugin preserves the user-generated HTML markup in the TinyMCE editor. Unlike other plugins this one allows developers to work in the HTML tab AND end-users to work in the WYSIWYG Visual tab at the same time! No longer will your HTML markup be completely munged into an unrecognizable form when you switch between those tabs. And you don't have to hang your users/editors out to dry when you hand off the project with a disabled Visual tab.

Comment: I tried html-editor-syntax-highlighter several months ago and I removed it. I do not rememer the details but it clutters code. I will try preserved-html-editor-markup-plus and report the result